# What Does This Error Message Mean

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

Linux newbie, Trying to Install live boot ubuntu 14.04 amd 64.  I get this message when booting from USB drive,

```
This kernel requires an x86-64 cpu but only detected an i686 cpu, unable to boot.
```

I have an hp desktop, 4 yrs old, and has a dual core athlon II X2 215 processor!! Any ideas, I've been trying to use a live disk or USB for 2 weeks on my system with Windows 7 but have not been able to get it to work yet.  I've tried the 32 bit, 64 bit over and over again!!!

I want to keep windows 7 on my system and just "TRY" ubuntu, not install or dual boot yet.  I use a program called speccy and it says that my system is 64 bit!  Also I have tried the ubuntu 32 bit with no results!!

Comment: Are you trying to dual-boot, replace Windows 7, or install inside of Windows 7?  The odd part about this, is that the Athlon II X2 215 is a 64-bit processor: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819103712

Answer (score 2):

That your processor only supports 32-bit, but you are trying to install the 64-bit version of Ubuntu. So download the 32-bit version instead and try again.

[follow this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu), and create a live usb of Ubuntu 32-bit and just click try instead of install. Please give me the exact error when it's not working this time.